# Visual Studio template export for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, project-template

I have an issue with namespaces in views when I export my template. The cs files have a variable to replace namespace. But cshtml (strongly typed view) contains parent project namespace for model.

How to make visual studio export views with variables?

I have tried to change template cshtml files and replaced namespace for model this way

```
@model $safeprojectname$.Models.ContactUsModel
```

and it didn't helped.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a resolution for my issue. Hope it will help someone.
I've replaced namespace in view with $safeprojectname$. Then I changed vstemplate file in line, related to changed cshtml to set parameter to true.